# Macro substitution in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

i am trying to make macrosubstitution in c#. Actually i'm trying to learn c#. I am experienced in Visual fox.

Anyway this what i need:

let's say i am trying to add a new control programmaticaly:

```
ProgressBar progressBar1 = new ProgressBar();
progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(516, 23);
progressBar1.Location = new Point(10, 36);
groupBox4.Controls.Add(progressBar1);
```

now i need to know a way how to replace the name o f the control (progressBar1) and tke the name for an string variable so i could create using a for statement more then one progress bar
?

any ideea?

Comment: You can put this code inside a loop without any problems.

Comment: you code is working naturally :), just put in for loop

Comment: you can use var myNameReplace = progressBar1; this will point to the same object. I don't know of anyway to use a defined string for the object name.

Comment: You don't want to do macro substitution in C#, it's not set up for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the code inside a for loop to create more than one instance of the progress bar, if you want to keep a reference of the items you can store them into a Dictionary, for example :

```
Dictionary<int, ProgressBar> progressBars = new Dictionary<int, ProgressBar>();

for(int i = 0; i < someValue; i++) {
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
progressBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(516, 23);
progressBar.Location = new Point(10, 36);
groupBox4.Controls.Add(progressBar);
progressBars.Add(i, progressBar);
}
```

So, now you can get back a desired progressbar looking in the dictionary, by the index(or by something else you define as key) ...

Example of getting back the progressbar with index 3(through the indexer) :

```
ProgressBar bar = progressBars[3]; 
bar.Value = //Assign some value
```

Comment: and how do i call the desired progressbar?

Comment: You can use the indexer of the Dictionary as you do for arrays, see the  updated answer ...

Answer (score 1):

progressBar1 is not the name of the control. Is the name of a variable of type ProgressBar used to work with the current instance of a ProgressBar.

Every class derived from Control has a property called [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx) of string type.

```
int xPos = 10;
int yPos = 36;

// Add 10 progressbars to the groupbox control collection
for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    yPos = yPos + (x * 30);
    ProgressBar progressBar1 = new ProgressBar(); 
    progressBar1.Name = "pgb" + x.ToString();
    progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(516, 23); 
    progressBar1.Location = new Point(10, yPos); 
    groupBox4.Controls.Add(progressBar1); 
}
```

To retrieve one of your added progress bars you can simply use the Controls object collection of the groupbox.

```
ProgresBar pb = groubBox4.Controls["pgb1"] as ProgressBar;
pb.Increment(1);
```

Comment: I think this answers the question because you are using the Name property.

Comment: OK this is working just fine. Now i need to know how do i call every progressbar individually?

Comment: oo i understand now. It's very simple. Tank you verry much. You're the best.